# How do I execute OpenFileDialog in a Textbox_Click event?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to make an app that when you click on the `TextBox` to select the file the `OpenFileDialog` opens automatically without the need to click on a button.

All i could find was [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.click.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) that does not explain how to implement it.

Should i add

```
[BrowsableAttribute(true)]
public event EventHandler Click
```

Somewhere?

Here is my code so far:

```
private void txtFile_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog OF = new OpenFileDialog();
        OF.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        OF.Filter = "All files (*) | *.*";

        if (OF.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            OF.FilterIndex = 0;
            OF.RestoreDirectory = true;
            txtFile.Text = (OF.FileName);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: Finally worked.

Comment: Please don't ask "Is it possible...?" questions here. Those usually get closed very quickly, because an answer is either "Yes, it is possible" or "No, it is not possible", and those answers are quite clearly not useful. Your effort also makes no sense - the TextChanged event will be fired on every single keystroke that changes the text, which seems pretty useless, and it has nothing to do with a mouse click. Every single answer that anyone has provides you've responded to with "doesn't work" with no other information. What do you want us to help you with?

Comment: Okay i made it work, not like i really liked it but it works! I used what Ria suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`OnEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onenter.aspx) event:

> Occurs when the control is entered.

and a sample code:

```
txtFile.Enter += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFile.Text))
        {
            var OF = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = "C:\\",
                Filter = "All files (*) | *.*"
            };

            if (OF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                OF.FilterIndex = 0;
                OF.RestoreDirectory = true;
                txtFile.Text = (OF.FileName);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I am not sure if im implementing it correctly but still doesnt work, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: add this code in form cunstructor or in `OnLoad` event. or add `Enter` event to your textbox in designer and paste inner code into `private void txtFile_Enter` method

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Focus** event in the text box to show the file dialog.

The focus event will fire once the control receive focus (clicked or tabbed into):

```
txtFile.Focus  += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var OF = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = "C:\\",
            Filter = "All files (*) | *.*"
        };

        if (OF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            OF.FilterIndex = 0;
            OF.RestoreDirectory = true;
            txtFile.Text = (OF.FileName);
        }
};
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This might work the thing is when my form is opened it is already on focus so maybe that is why the event is not being triggered.

Comment: If so I'd suggested you to use the Enter event as Rio suggested. It should work. Make sure to assign the event delegate on the FormLoad or FormLoaded event.

Answer (score 1):

Simple set the `TextBox` `MouseClick` event to your desired method:

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: @GustavoRodríguezSuarez, you can set the event via Properties pane or via code 'textBox1.MouseClick += textBox1_MouseClick;' in constructor. no so hard

Comment: When all three answers don't work for you, then the problem is somewhere else maybe a misconfiguration

Comment: Yea, i dont know what it was, it works now, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mouse Click Event

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog OF = new OpenFileDialog();
        OF.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        OF.Filter = "All files (*) | *.*";

        if (OF.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            OF.FilterIndex = 0;
            OF.RestoreDirectory = true;
           txtFile.Text = (OF.FileName);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to textbox's properties then click on event button.
you will find click event = blank. click dropdown menue.Select *openToolStripMenuItem_Click*, for example, if you have already opening "open  file dialog"  in his program.

Note: No extra code is required